# Visual Studio 2008, How can I set it to remove tabs when I backspace rather than spaces?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, editor, tabs

In Visual Studio 2008, it seems that when I tab on a line it inserts either 4 spaces or a tab, however - when I backspace it removes a tab as if it were 4 spaces, one space at a time..

I checked the text-editor settings in Tools.. tried both use spaces and use tabs, neither seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Pete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe I'm just crazy, but why don't you just press **Shift + Tab** instead of backspace if you want to get rid of the tabs?

Comment: Apologies for the late comment, yea I guess you are right, keep tabs isn't what I wanted - which was to get rid of tabs and get spaces instead.

Answer (score 4):

Aha!! Hi Robert, that's what I did try.. However, I needed to change this setting in the 'All Languages' section so it applied to every type of page.

"Keep tabs"

Thanks
Pete

Comment: Please see Pospodo's answer, it makes more sense as a correct answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's probably not writing tabs its converting tabs to spaces when you press tab. There is a setting in the options that tells VS how many spaces to insert when pressing tab,  Maybe you can set it to actually insert a tab instead and backspace would then remove the tab.  I've heard it's quite common to use spaces not tabs that's why its built into VS i guess.